# fixed menu position with 100% height body

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, menu, fixed

I dont really understand why my example dont work, but something like that with bootstrap works perfectly.

```
<html style="height: 100%;">
<body style="height: 100%; padding-top: 70px;">   
    <div style="height: 100%; border: red solid;"></div>      
</body>
</html>
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/QVmjd/2/

Why my 100% height is more than 100%? Threrfore in http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/, all is ok?

UPD:
more simple example with bootstrap http://fiddle.jshell.net/C3vrB/1/

UPD2: Examples became more clear to understand difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all you need to do this:

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

and then your padding will be count as part of 100% height or width

Answer (score 2):

the `padding-top` extends or adds 70px

```
  <body style="height: 100%; padding-top: 70px;">
```

Comment: http://fiddle.jshell.net/C3vrB/
same body padding 60px; but works with bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

It's due to the way CSS handles the `box model`. Check out the [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html) or the [CSS Tricks rundown](http://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/).

Essentially, your box's height is set by the `height`, and any additional styling such as `padding`, `margin` and `border` are applied to the *outside* of this size, so your element is being extended by the `padding-top: 70px;` to be 70 pixels higher than 100%;

If you need padding, you can either add padding by percentage:

```
height: 85%;
padding-top: 15%;
```

Bringing your box height to the total of 100%, or you could have the outer box a fixed height and add padding to the child elements, which does not effect the box size of the parent.

There is also the option of using the `box-sizing` property in CSS, which, when set to `border-box`, will render the padding, borders etc inside of the declared width and height of the box.

Comment: thanks, I will try to read CSS Tricks.
But I need exactly 70px, not percentage